# How can I stop a jquery animation when mousedown is released?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bind, css, mousedown

Right now I have a simple button set up that animates when the mouse is pressed and reverses the effects of that animation when the mouse is released. The animation changes the 'top', 'left', and 'box-shadow' properties. I had to use a special jquery plugin in order to allow jquery's .animate() function to affect the element's box-shadow. For ease of reference, here is a [GitHub repository of my current example](https://github.com/brianjsullivan/box-shadow-animation).

The problem is, even if the mouse button is released immediately, the animation completes before it continues to reverse itself. The desired effect is for the user to control whether or not the button is moving "up" or "down" by holding or releasing the mouse button. See [this example](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/) (last box on the right) to get an idea of what I'd like to achieve.

In my research so far, it seems that binding/unbinding should be used to accomplish this, but the examples I've seen didn't deal with stopping an animation before it had completed.

Comment: Sorry for anyone not using Chrome, I only optimized the code to display properly in that browser as I'm simply testing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery to animate stuff,

You can use .stop() to

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

OR

You can also use .finish() to

> Stop the currently-running animation, remove all queued animations, and complete all animations for the matched elements.

Then you can revert back to element's original values as the animation has stopped.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I'm using jQuery to carry out these animations despite knowing it can be done more cleanly using CSS3 animations. This decision was made as a matter of circumstance (cross-browser compatibility).

Comment: I was able to successfully implement this by adding a `.stop()` call directly before each `.animate()` call within the two event handlers. At first this caused issues because the `top` and `left` positioning properties were animated using `+=5px` & `-=5px` causing the button to move when the mouse was clicked rapidly. This has been changed to apply static property values to `top` and `left` and it works quite well!